# Connect to container's localhost interface in Docker

Tags: mongodb, docker

Is it possible to connect to a process running in a Docker container but exactly via container's loopback interface ?

Basically I am looking for this option:

```
docker run ... -p 12345:127.0.0.1:12345 ...
```

This is rejected by Docker.

The use case is for example to setup Mongo admin user via [Localhost Exception](https://docs.mongodb.com/v3.4/core/security-users/#localhost-exception)

Comment: Take a look at the [docs for `docker run`](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/run/#expose-incoming-ports).  You have the argument to the `-p` option mixed up.

Comment: I don't see there an option to specify the container interface. I am looking for establishing connection via container loopback if not via host's loopback

Answer (score 0):

You have the port mapping slightly wrong.  Try it like this:

```
$ docker run -itd -p 27117:27017 mongo
```

so `27117` is the port you can connect to outwith the docker container, and `27017` is the port mongod is running on within docker

So when I connect the mongo shell I can connect to the mongod within docker like:

```
$ mongo --port 27117
```

Answer (score 0):

Try like this :

**Step 1 :**

pulling mongo image from docker.

```
docker pull mongo
```

**Step 2 :**

Create new directory for storing mongodb data in you shared location like **/home/user/databases/mongo**

**Step 3:**

Run mongodb from docker image using below command

if you want change the mongodb port like 12345 set it in the command. 27017 is globally declared in docker you cannot change it but i want locally change the mongodb port like 12345

```
docker run -d -p 12345:27017 -v /home/user/databases/mongo:/data/db --name mongodb mongo
```